# Upload error: Could not connect to DataPusher. error in ckan 2.4.3

Tags: datastore, ckan

I'm trying to upload my dataset to datastore.

I create dataset and try to upload dataset to datastore with "Upload to datastore" menu in ckan interface.

I got "Upload error: Could not connect to DataPusher." error message in web not in any log(ckan log, datapusher log)

[image]

This is contents of my development.ini

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:MYPASS@localhost/ckan_default
ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:MYPASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:MYPASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.default_fts_lang = english
ckan.datastore.default_fts_index_method = gist
ckan.site_url =  http://ckan.daniel.com

ckan.site_id = default
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan
ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore datapusher
ckan.views.default_views = image_view text_view recline_view

ckan.preview.direct = png jpg gif
ckan.preview.loadable = html htm rdf+xml owl+xml xml n3 n-triples turtle plain atom csv tsv rss txt json

ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan
ckan.max_resource_size = 10
ckan.max_image_size = 2
ckan.datapusher.formats = csv xls xlsx tsv application/csv application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
ckan.datapusher.url = http://ckan.daniel.com:8080/
```

and datapusher is running.

```
# curl http://ckan.daniel.com:8800
    {
      "help": "\n        Get help at:\n        http://ckan-service-provider.readthedocs.org/."
    }
```

I use ckan 2.4.3 + postgresql 9.1 + rhel 6.6 + solr 5.4.

Am I missing something datastore configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: In the .ini file you have `ckan.datapusher.url = http://ckan.daniel.com:8080/`, but apparently your datapusher is running on port 8800.

Comment: Hi I change port of datapusher url. but the error message is same.

Comment: now is it ok ? how to succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the last line of production.ini from

```
ckan.datapusher.url = http://ckan.daniel.com:8080/
```

to

```
ckan.datapusher.url = http://ckan.daniel.com:8800/
```